# o.bind.apply(arguments);

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at JQuery Tiny Pub/Sub, which looks something like this:

```
(function($){
  var o = $({});

  $.subscribe = function() {
    o.bind.apply( o, arguments );
  };

  ...

})(jQuery);
```

What I don't get is, since the code is calling o.bind, the "this" inside bind is o anyway, therefore there is no reason to use apply.

In other words,

```
o.bind(arguments)
```

and

```
o.bind.apply(o, arguments)
```

here should be identical shouldn't they? The why o.bind.apply(o, arguements)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.apply` takes an *array* of arguments to pass, so they're not the same thing. Consider this:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}

foo.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]);
// Prints:
// 1
// 2
// 3

foo([1, 2, 3]);
// Prints:
// [1,2,3]
// undefined
// undefined
```

You may be confusing it with `.call`, which would certainly be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `bind` and `apply`. Bind takes the arguments and apply gets a scope and an array with the arguments.

To make this more clear. This would be the same:

```
o.bind(1,2,3);

o.apply(o, [1,2,3]);
```

Comment: `o` isn't a function, so it doesn't have an `.apply()` method. If you were thinking of the ECMAScript `.bind()`, that one takes a calling context argument just like `.apply()`, but individual arguments like `.call()`.